# How to raise or lower the log level in puppet master?

Tags: puppet

I am using puppet 3.2.3, passenger and apache on CentOS 6. I have 680 compute nodes in a cluster along with 8 gateways users use to log in to the cluster and submit jobs. All the nodes and gateways are under puppet control. I recently upgraded from 2.6. The master logs to syslog as desired, but how to change the log level for the master escapes me. I appear to have the choice of --debug, or nothing. Debug logs far too much detail, while not using that switch simply logs each time passneger/apache launch a new worker to handle incoming connections.

I find nothing in the on-line docs about doing this. What I want is to log each time a nodes hits the server; but I do not need to see the compiled catalogue, or resources in/var/log/messages.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack, but here is how I solved the problem. In the file (config.ru) that passenger uses to launch puppet via rack middleware, which in my system lives in `/usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd`, I noticed these lines

```
require 'puppet/util/command_line'
run Puppet::Util::CommandLine.new.execute
```

So, this I edited to become

```
require 'puppet/util/command_line'
Puppet::Util::Log.level = :info
run Puppet::Util::CommandLine.new.execute
```

I suppose other choices for Log.level could be :warn and others.